# Adding consistency statements to Peano arithmetic allows more instances of transfinite induction?

Tags: peano-arithmetic, transfinite-induction

Consider the hierarchy given by $\cal S_0 =$ first-order Peano arithmetic, $\cal S_{\alpha+1}=\cal S_{\alpha} + Con(S_\alpha)$ (a consistency statement for $\cal S_\alpha$), and if $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, $\cal S_\alpha=\bigcup_{\beta < \alpha} \cal S_\beta$.

Peano arithmetic proves transfinite induction for ordinals below $\epsilon_0$. Is there an $\alpha$ such that $\cal S_\alpha$ proves transfinite induction for longer initial segments? If so, is there a fixed point $\alpha$ s.t. $\epsilon_0 < \alpha \leq \Gamma_0$ and $\cal S_\alpha$ proves transfinite induction for all ordinals below $\alpha$ but not beyond?

Comment: Depends on what exactly you mean by transfinite induction (which is really a second-order statement) in PA, but under most readings, adding true $\Pi^0_1$ sentences does not increase the length of available transfinite induction.

Comment: If we have a coding of ordinals below $\Gamma_0$ with numbers s.t. $\bar \alpha$ is a name for (the code of) $\alpha$ and $\prec$ is the smaller-than relation for ordinals defined over the coding, by transfinite induction I mean: $$\forall \alpha(\forall \beta\prec\alpha\phi(\beta)\rightarrow\phi(\alpha))\rightarrow\forall\alpha \phi(\alpha)$$ and by transfinite induction up to an ordinal $\delta$ I mean
$$\forall \alpha(\forall \beta\prec\alpha\phi(\beta)\rightarrow\phi(\alpha))\rightarrow\forall\alpha \prec\bar \delta \phi(\alpha)$$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Over PRA, the transfinite induction schema up to $\epsilon_0$ for primitive recursive formulas implies not just the consistency of PA, but also its $\Sigma^0_1$-soundness (i.e., the uniform $\Sigma^0_1$-reflection principle for PA). As such, it is not provable in any consistent extension of PA by a set of $\Pi^0_1$ sentences, because of Gödel’s theorem.

Comment: Related: see Henry Towsner's answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/155329/what-is-the-proof-theoretic-ordinal-of-pa-conpa-pa-conpa-conpa-etc.